# How to paste excel data into a powerpoint table already existing in a presentation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to paste a large range of data from Excel (say A1:B2000) into a powerpoint presentation, with each slide having a table with 40 rows of data from excel in it. I am struggling to finally paste the range into the table in powerpoint.

In more detail, I have worked on 2 possible solutions: A) pasting the Excel data as a new table into a powerpoint slide, and then reformat it; or B), as requested here because I think it should be the better solution, pasting the Excel data into existing tables in powerpoint.

I have the code to copy a range and select a cell within a table in a powerpoint slide into which I want to paste the range of excel cells, but I do not know how to do the final step, pasting the Excel data into the powerpoint table.

```
Private Sub pptpaste2()
Dim r As Range
Dim powerpointapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim mypresentation As Object
Dim myslide As Object
Dim myshape As Object
Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
Dim ppTbl As Object

'code to insert excel rows into tables already existing in powerpoint presentation slides

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("listdata").Range("B3:C11")
Set powerpointapp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
Set mypresentation = powerpointapp.Presentations("RoughVBApres.ppxt")
Set pptLayout = mypresentation.Slides(3).CustomLayout
Set myslide = mypresentation.Slides(3)
powerpointapp.Visible = True
powerpointapp.Activate

 If powerpointapp Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "PowerPoint Presentation is not open, aborting."
       Exit Sub
     End If

   'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
     If Err.Number = 429 Then
       MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
       Exit Sub
     End If
 On Error GoTo 0

'copy range in excel that you want to paste into table on powerpoint
r.Copy

 'Make the presentation the active presentation
    mypresentation.Windows(1).Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False

' find on Slide Number 3 which object ID is of Table type
With powerpointapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes
    For i = 1 To .Count
        If .Item(i).HasTable Then
            ShapeNum = i
        End If
    Next
End With

' assign Slide Table object
Set ppTbl = powerpointapp.ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(ShapeNum)

' select the Table cell you want to copy to
ppTbl.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.Select
```

I believe I have done all of the code up to finally pasting the data into the powerpoint slide table. 
I have tried

```
powerpointapp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
```

and variants of that which are suggested elsewhere online, but this doesn't seem to work. I would like guidance as to how to finally paste my copied range into the existing table in powerpoint, if this is possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: delete `Application.CutCopyMode = False` and it may run OK.  I tried  your code in PP 2007 after deleting the above statement and with `ExecuteMso "Paste"`  (due to version constraints) and worked fine

Comment: You made my day.